# Should I rollover my Fidelity 401(k) to a Vanguard IRA?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, retirement

I'm leaving a job where I have a Fidelity 401(k). I plan to rollover my Fidelity 401(k) into an IRA after I leave the job.

I like Fidelity. But most of my portfolio is invested in Vanguard ETFs, and I plan to continue investing in them.

Should I rollover my Fidelity 401k to a Vanguard IRA? Or should I stick with a Fidelity IRA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy Vanguard ETFs commission-free at Fidelity. If you wanted to buy Vanguard mutual funds (and were opposed to the Fidelity equivalents), that would be a different story. But with ETFs either brokerage is fine, so it's really a matter of personal preference, and you can't go wrong with either. Note that rolling over a Fidelity 401(k) to a Fidelity IRA might be easier than to a Vanguard IRA, so that could impact your decision.

Answer (score 3):

Compare fees and convenience of access.

If you are planning to invest in Vanguard ETFs anyway it's probably easiest and cheapest to open a Vanguard IRA.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes all that much difference.  I like having accounts with two different companies just for diversity.  If someone manages to hack into one account, then I still have the other to use while the first is being fixed.  Likewise, if I'm ever disabled for a spell, the person who has my health care POA can draw funds from account A, but can't be tempted to clean out both and head for someplace with no extradition :-)

Comment: Your Healthcare POA allows your designated attorney to withdraw funds _only_ from Account A but not from Accounts B, C, and D?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: The way I wrote it, yes.  The person doesn't even know those other funds exist.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you almost certainly *should not* rollover your 401(k) into an IRA, if your 401(k) has low-cost investment options that meet your needs.

Two big reasons:

1. If you go bankrupt (or get sued for all your money), [your 401(k) is protected at the federal level](https://rpgplanner.com/ira-rollover/#:%7E:text=Potential%20for%20Better%20Asset%20Protection,creditor%20claims%20under%20federal%20law.), whereas your IRA may or may not be protected (at the state level).
2. If your income is ever high enough that you're not allowed to (directly) contribute to a Roth IRA, you'll still *effectively* be able to contribute to a Roth IRA by doing a [Backdoor Roth](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Backdoor_Roth), but *it won't work* if you have money in a traditional IRA (read the "Cautions" section for the gory details).

Several smaller reasons:

1. The money will be out of the market for days or weeks while it's being transferred to an IRA *and* to a new custodian.
2. Why go through the hassle? Fidelity is a perfectly fine provider, with very good customer service (I would say *substantially better* than Vanguard in the last few years), and presumably you have good low-fee, passive investment options that meet your needs in the Fidelity 401(k).

Now, if your old 401(k) were in a crummy provider with high fees, poor investment choices, and poor service, [the choice would be very different](https://rpgplanner.com/ira-rollover), but if it's Fidelity vs. Vanguard, I'd argue that you're much better off leaving it in in the 401(k).

You will always retain the *option value* of being able to roll it over into an IRA if you need the specific advantages of an IRA (e.g. early withdrawal without penalty)… but you generally can't "go back" in the opposite direction, since most future employers' 401(k) plans won't let you roll an IRA into them… though you *can* typically do a 401(k)→401(k) rollover when taking a new job.

---

For what it's worth, at one point I had *four* 401(k)s and profit-sharing plans from previous employers at Fidelity. I was paying no fees for any of it, but that did get a little tedious to manage, so I asked Fidelity to roll them all into the *one* 401(k) of the most recent employer. (I was slightly surprised, but they did it .) Took a couple half-hour phone calls and 2 days of the money being “out of the market,” and now I have it all in one bucket with all the advantages of the 401(k), including the “option value” to rollover into an IRA in the future *if I need it*.

Comment: " Fidelity is a perfectly fine provider, with very good customer service (I would say substantially better than Vanguard in the last few years)," +1, matches my experience